# Drupal: How do I pass profile tokens to user profile page?

Tags: drupal-6

On the panel pages for my user profiles, the titles for each user are their usernames (such as jblow for Joe Blow). The uid is passed to the page and, presently the title is set to %user:name. Is there some way I can use tokens, or some other solution, to get the users specific first and last name to the profile page?

I am using the core profile module, as well, if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can check this modules:

http://drupal.org/project/token_custom

http://drupal.org/project/token_profile